# Disable hibernate jpa log in persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, logging, log4j

How I can disable the hibernate jpa logs in console?

Is it possible to disable them in `persistence.xml` file?

The logs are same this:

```
nov 27, 2017 1:03:02 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated j
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be more sources of those loggs popping up. Try these as remedy:

**1)** Check `log4j.logger.org.hibernate / log4j.logger.javax.persistence` in your log4j config file and set it to error / none

**2)** In your `persistence.xml` in `<persistence-unit><properties>` tag set:

```
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=false
```